# how to choose a value in dropdown which is not in select tag ..?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I am using `selenium-RC` for my automation with `java` (Eclipse Kepler) . I am facing some issues with a selection of a `option` in a `drop down list` which is not in `select` tag it is in `span`.

I want to test a page where their is a drop-down list for selection of city name. the drop-down appears only when I give some value e.g for "Bangalore" I have to type "ban" so the drop-down appears and then I select the city Bangalore either with "`mouse click`" or either with "`down-arrow and enter key`" but when I run my selenium rc script it fails after typing "ban" the drop-down doesn't appears. i tried using both  xpath and id in select command,click command. I am stuck over here please please someone help me  to solve this issue.I think it is dynamic and based on `JavaScript functions`.One more ..The next two drop down are depended  on the first drop-down(i.e the second and third drop-down are hidden and first drop-down is shown by_default.)
I am sending the link of page where i am trying to test script: https://pizzaonline.dominos.co.in

I tried using following commands:-

1:

```
w.click("//*[@id='homedeliveryform']/div[1]/span/a/span[1]");
w.click("//*[@id='ui-active-menuitem']");
```

2:

```
w.type("//*[@id='homedeliveryform']/div[1]/span/input","ban");
w.click("//*[@id='ui-active-menuitem']");
```

3:

```
w.select(" id=combobox", "value=BANGALORE");
```

4:

```
w.type(" id=combobox", "value=BANGALORE");
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception when you run the code? If yes then share the stacktrace

Comment: No I am not getting any exception. just as soon as I entered the value for particular city name with type command the second drop-down is not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey thank you so much for the help. I solved this by

```
 w.keyPressNative(String.valueOf(KeyEvent.VK_B));
          w.keyPressNative(String.valueOf(KeyEvent.VK_A));
          w.keyPressNative(String.valueOf(KeyEvent.VK_N));
          w.keyPressNative("40");                           // down arrow key
          Thread.sleep(4000);
          w.keyPressNative("10");                           //Enter key
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem. This is how I solved it:

1. Find the arrow button in the combobox and click it, the dropdown list will appear.
2. The dropdown list doesn't really have anything to do with the combobox, it is a separate list wich is just displayed in a correct position so that it looks like it belongs to the combobox. The dropdown list is actually an `<ul>`-element, which doesn't seem to be very easily found. Anyway there are many `<li>`-elements with `<a>`-elements in them, and those hold the texts.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply but I tried that but it doesn't work. I am  getting an ERROR: Element id=ui-active-menuitem not found.w. click("//*[@id='homedeliveryform']/div[1]/span/a/span[1]");
Thread.sleep(2000);
w.click("id=ui-active-menuitem");

Comment: hey when found in firepath all <li> in the <ul> has the same xpath

Comment: You can't select them by id. You must select by text. I'm sorry I can't telp you with java.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see you are trying to select a webelement(Bangalore) from a dropdown which is not visible till the time you click on it. Here are the ways by which you are able to select a hidden web element.

**1st way:** it is not the problem to click any element using the same js. As you know how to get any option the last actions remaning is to perform a click. This should work for you:

```
WebElement hiddenWebElement =driver.findElement(By(..selector of the element....));
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()",hiddenWebElement);
```

**2nd way:**

```
String cssSelector= ...//i gave them in your previous question
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\'"+cssSelector+"\');");
    stringBuilder.append("x.click();");
    js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
```

**3rd way:** using actions builder, advanced user actions API. You can read about it here And code will be smth like that:

```
WebElement mnuElement;
WebElement submnuElement;
mnEle = driver.findElement(By.Id("mnEle")).click();
sbEle = driver.findElement(By.Id("sbEle")).click();

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
// Move cursor to the Main Menu Element
builder.moveToElement(mnEle).Perform();
// Giving 5 Secs for submenu to be displayed
Thread.sleep(5000L);
// Clicking on the Hidden SubMenu
driver.findElement(By.Id("sbEle")).click();
```

Answer (score -4):

In the below scenario what I did is...(dropdwon is in the table)

1. clicked the cell
2. get all cell values from the table(probably the list will be configured as table or list .. here it is table)
3. traverse through all the cells.
4. click on the required value based on the cell value.

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.id("ms__id3")).click();
   WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.className("combo-list-table"));
   allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
   for (WebElement row : allRows) 
   {
   cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
   for (WebElement cell : cells) 
   {   
   if(cell.getAttribute("text").equalsIgnoreCase("Business"))
   {
   cell.click();
   }
   }
   }
   ```

Hope this will help...:)